# How can I find element by two attributes? c# webdriver

Tags: c#, css, selenium, xpath

I need to find elements by class and text it contains. I tried like this but nothing worked, please help(for me it is better to select using css, but xpath is ok too):

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[contains(@class,'TestClass') and .//text()='TestText']"))
Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("td.TestClass:contains('TestText')"))
```

elements:

```
  <td class="TestClass"> TestText</td>
  <td class="TestClass"> TestText1</td>
  <td class="TestClass"> TestText2</td>...
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You can try using the following XPATH expression:

   ```
   //td[@class='TestClass'][text()='TestText']
   ```
2. Use FindElements instead of FindElement. You can find all td elements and then just loop through them looking for the text you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use below xpath:-

```
//td[text()=' TestText']
```

OR

```
//td[@class='TestClass' and text()=' TestText']
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

A different approach by using a **CSS Selector** and LINQ in C#:

```
    var elements = WebDriver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("td.TestClass'"]));
    var theElement = elements.FirstOrDefault( e => e.Text.Contains("TestText1"));
```